# Prevent automatic namespace prefix

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, namespaces

I have an xml file with the following structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="uid">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  </metadata>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <spine toc="ncx"></spine>
  <guide></guide>
</package>
```

I am programmatically adding elements to the structure like this:

```
    XDocument opfDoc = XDocument.Load(opfFile);

    //create the xmlnamespaces required for the <metadata> section of the opf file.
    var dc = (XNamespace)"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
    var opf = (XNamespace)"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf";

    //**add book metadata
    var meta = opfDoc.Root.Element(opf + "metadata");
    meta.Add(new XElement(dc + "title", bookMetaData[0].bookTitle));
```

Technically, this is working, however the resulting xml file is changing the **metadata** section to **opf:metadata**, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="uid">
  <opf:metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <dc:title>Microsoft Project 2013 &amp; 2016 Fundamentals</dc:title>
```

The **opf:metadata** was never in the original file and I never specifically add this. If I change the original meta variable to look like this, I get a null reference and cannot add new elements:

```
var meta = opfDoc.Root.Element("metadata");
```

How I simply add code to the metadata section without adding the namespace prefix to the metadata element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have duplicate namespace declarations for `http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf` - once as the default namespace, and once with the `opf` prefix.  You can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/27cfnL) that simply loading the XML and writing it back out again will result in the prefix being added - it's nothing you're doing.

You can remove the unused `xmlns:opf` declaration from the `metadata` element and then LINQ to XML will round trip the XML correctly. I don't think there's any other way you'll change what it's doing - it looks up the prefix by checking up the tree, and the `opf` prefix is the first it will come across.

It's worth noting that both representations are semantically the same, however. The difference is not important.

Comment: Thank you for this. Reading the specification I am working against, it would appear to recommend the use of both opf's. Looking at how some third-party programs output their files, they also use both opf's. I will have to do some testing to determine if your recommendation impacts my product's usage. Thank you. http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0_latest.htm#Section2.2